# How to show data from a remote .csv file in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, papaparse

im trying to extract data from this .csv link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MinCiencia/Datos-COVID19/master/output/producto74/paso_a_paso_T.csv
I'm using React Papaparse and Im able to console.log the Arrays with no problem,
The problem is that this branch tracks info since 2020 and I only want to show the LATEST date available (they update this branch every 2-3 days), and I only need the part that says "comuna_residencia" and "paso", I don't need any of the other information.
I have tested a variaty of formulas, but can't manage to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Okey guys, I managed to display the information with useState and useEffect as seen below:

`````
import { readRemoteFile } from "react-papaparse";

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    readRemoteFile(
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MinCiencia/Datos-COVID19/master/output/producto74/paso_a_paso_T.csv",
      {
        complete: (results) => {
          setData(results);
        },
      }
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {data ? (
        <p>{JSON.stringify(data)}</p>
      ) : (
        <div className="loader">Loading...</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App; ````


My question is, how I can filter to just get the last date available and also just the "comuna_residencia" and "paso"


Thanks in advance.
`````